# SNMP only works on localhost

Tags: centos, monitoring, snmp

I'm trying to monitor a remote server using SNMP v3 and Centos 6.4.

When I use snmpwalk to test the configuration on the server I'm trying to monitor:

```
snmpwalk [connection parameters...] subdomain.mydomain.com
```

or

```
snmpwalk [connection parameters...] localhost
```

It works. But when I try the same on a remote server I got the following error:

```
snmpwalk: Timeout
```

I have disabled iptables on both servers, when I check if the service is listening I get:

```
tcp  0  0 localhost.localdomain:smux *:*  LISTEN  11989/snmpd         
udp  0  0 *:snmp                     *:*          11989/snmpd
```

I also tried increasing the timeout value on the client side...

I have run out of ideas about what could be going on. Can anyone help me?

Comment: How have you configured snmpd? Check your `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`.

Comment: It has the default configuration + "rouser [myuser]"

Comment: That's not enough information. We need to know who can access this device via snmp. This is defined in snmpd.conf as @Feussy has mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the ability to query the net-snmp agent is limited to the local host with the exception of the System MIB. In order to allow access to the other MIBs (or any if you've further restricted access) you need to examine the Access Control section of the /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file on your server.